# Pogrammatically get foreign keys for a table in jOOQ

Tags: java, orm, jooq

Is there a way to programmatically list all the [Fields](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/Field.html) which are a [Foreign Key](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/ForeignKey.html) in jOOQ? It generates a lot of static constants to foreign keys, but there is no good way to programmatically access these.

Example, I have a table `Orders` with a foreign key field `customer_id`. In jOOQ, say I have a reference to said [table object](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/Table.html) for `Orders`, there does not appear to be a way to programmatically get a reference to the `customer_id` jooq field object. So my only solution now is to manually make these mappings somewhere using a literal map datastructure. Seems like jooq would have been able to do this for me, am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to navigate the jOOQ meta model. Your description isn't complete, but I'm assuming, you would want to do something like this:

```
for (ForeignKey<?, ?> fk : ORDERS.getReferencesTo(CUSTOMER))
    for (Field<?> fkField : fk.getFields())
        System.out.println(fkField);
```

Comment: Yeah that was it, thank you. I tried searching "keys" or "Foreign" and wasn't finding it in the long list of api calls. TY for the prompt response.